# How can I resolve the tcl error in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I run the file add books it works fine but when I import the file "add books" inside another file "main.py" I am getting an error.
In the "add book" file I have used a image "SISHYA SCHOOL blur.png" this is the background for my program.
Now if I run the file "add book" I am getting output like
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waShf.png)

But when I am importing the "add book" file to another file "main.py"
the background image doesn't get displayed in the output
[this is the main.py code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKLF2.png)

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OssDh.png)

```
def addBook(): 

global bookInfo1 ,bookInfo2, bookInfo3, bookInfo4, Canvas1, con, cur, bookTable, root

mypass = "*****"
mydatabase="db"

con = pymysql.connect( host="localhost", user="root", password=mypass, database=mydatabase)
cur = con.cursor()

# Enter Table Names here
bookTable = "books" # Book Table    

root = Tk()
root.title("Library")
root.geometry("600x500")

background = PhotoImage(file ="F:\\12th project\\img\\SISHYA SCHOOL blur.png")
bg1_label = Label(root, image = background) 
bg1_label.place(x = 0, y = 0)

# Book ID
lb1 = Label(root, text="Book ID : ", bg='black', fg='white')
lb1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.2, relheight=0.08)

bookInfo1 = Entry(root)
bookInfo1.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.62, relheight=0.08)

# Title
lb2 = Label(root, text="Title : ", bg='black', fg='white')
lb2.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.35, relheight=0.08)

bookInfo2 = Entry(root)
bookInfo2.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.62, relheight=0.08)

# Book Author
lb3 = Label(root, text="Author : ", bg='black', fg='white')
lb3.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.50, relheight=0.08)

bookInfo3 = Entry(root)
bookInfo3.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.50, relwidth=0.62, relheight=0.08)

# Book Status
lb4 = Label(root, text="Status(Avail/issued) : ", bg='black', fg='white')
lb4.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.65, relheight=0.08)

bookInfo4 = Entry(root)
bookInfo4.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.65, relwidth=0.62, relheight=0.08)

#Submit Button
SubmitBtn = Button(root, text="SUBMIT", bg='#d1ccc0', fg='black', command=bookRegister)
SubmitBtn.place(relx=0.28, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.18, relheight=0.08)

quitBtn = Button(root, text="Quit", bg='#f7f1e3', fg='black', command=root.destroy)
quitBtn.place(relx=0.53, rely=0.9, relwidth=0.18, relheight=0.08)

root.mainloop()
```

[Tthis is the code snippet of add book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kih42.png)

Comment: Post the entire error code as text, not image.

Comment: It looks like this error is caused by having multiple instances of Tk. Change Tk to Toplevel in `addBook`

Comment: @Henry can u tell me the code i should add to the addbook.py idk what's top level

Comment: Change `root = Tk()` to `root = Toplevel()`. Toplevel works the same as Tk but you shouldn't have problems with images